# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError, but all jar files are in place

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, xssf

SOLVED, I GOT IT TO WORK

I just completed my first real JAVA program. It is a program which lets you open a .xlsx file and the program extracts data from this file and shows this in a textArea.

In eclipse, the program works totally fine, but the exported jar doesn't. Once the project is exported I open it in CMD with java -jar c://...... and it opens just fine. However when I try to open the excel file I get this error:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bklcb.png)

So basically one of the needed .jar files seems not to be available in runtime. However I believe all of the needed poi-3.9 and xmlbeans are available. See this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="src/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="src/poi-3.9-20121203.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="src/poi-examples-3.9-20121203.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="src/poi-excelant-3.9-20121203.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="src/poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="src/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="src/poi-scratchpad-3.9-20121203.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="src/log4j-1.2.13.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="src/junit-3.8.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="src/commons-logging-1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="commons-collections4-4.1-javadoc.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="commons-collections4-4.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="src/commons-codec-1.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="poi-ooxml-3.9.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/commons-codec-1.10.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/commons-io-2.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/commons-lang3-3.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/cssparser-0.9.20.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/htmlunit-2.23.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/htmlunit-core-js-2.23.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/httpclient-4.5.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/httpcore-4.4.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/httpmime-4.5.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/jetty-io-9.2.18.v20160721.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/jetty-util-9.2.18.v20160721.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/neko-htmlunit-2.23.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/sac-1.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/serializer-2.7.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/websocket-api-9.2.18.v20160721.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/websocket-client-9.2.18.v20160721.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/websocket-common-9.2.18.v20160721.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/xml-apis-1.4.01.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="src/jsoup-1.10.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="src/dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="src/selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="src/stax-api-1.0.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/poi-ooxml-3.11.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="src/xbean-2.0.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

See also my Order and Exporttab in the build path configurations.

[Export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQmrs.png)

Am I missing something? Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
I made some changes and all necessary jars are in the lib/ folder of my project. If I export jar and view the jar contents with: jar tf "location.jar". I get the following. So I believe this means that everything is exported nicely. Any suggestions on what might be going wrong, because i keep getting the same error.

[image: Contents of JAR and Classpath]

Comment: why do you have libraries in `src`?

Comment: Try to open jar file with archiver and check that you can find jar files of libraries in lib folder to be sure they you jar packed in correct way.

Comment: still 2 checks are missing in dependent jar files so just check all them and then try, might help you

Comment: do accept the answer so that others can benefit from what you went through

Answer (score 2):

This is because eclipse reads your class-path dependencies and includes them in the runtime but for running the exported jar through the `java -jar` command, you will have to add the `-cp <your-jar-locations-semicolon-separated>` so that jvm knows that the jars are to be included in the class-path while execution.

alternatively, look into building a shaded jar which contains all your dependent jars in the exported jar.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer! I am not sure how to add -cp <your-jar-locations-semicolon-separated>. I hava a lot of jar's, do I have to add them all in the -cp line?

Comment: unfortunately, yes. but you can create a shaded jar also to include all the dependencies. there are ways to do it and u will find relevant questions here

Comment: does `-cp` work with `-jar`? From java tool description "When you use the -jar option, the specified JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other class path settings are ignored." I believe `-cp` will only be used for the main JAR file, other locations must be specified inside the manifest file.

Comment: So based on the output that is displayed in the image from my edit, how should I specify my classpath settings inside the manifest?

Comment: create a manifest file, e.G. "manifest.txt" (or let eclipse do it); add the [Class-Path] (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#classpath) attribute to it; and use this file when creating the JAR - assuming you are using the JAR File export tool in eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Carlos. I did what you told me but I still get the same error. In the description of the exported Jar all necessary .jar files are exported so I am really stumped at this point why the jar has problems with finding the necessary XSSF files. Do you hava any other ideas?